# How to increment count of occurences of column value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have the following column names:

- customer_email
- increment_id
- other_id (psuedo name)
- created_at

`increment_id` and `other_id` will be unique, `customer_email` will have duplicates. As the results are returned I want to know what number of occurance of the email it is.

For each row, I want to know how many times the`customer_email` value has shown up *so far*. There will be an `order by` clause at the end for the `created_at` field and I plan to also add a where clause of `where occurrences < 2`

I am querying > 5 million rows but performance isn't *too* important because I'll be running this as a report on a  read-replica database from production. In my use case, I will sacrifice performance for robustness.

```
| customer_email | incremenet_id | other_id | created_at          | occurances <- I want this |
|----------------|---------------|----------|---------------------|---------------------------|
| joe@test.com   | 1             | 81       | 2019-11-00 00:00:00 | 1                         |
| sue@test.com   | 2             | 82       | 2019-11-00 00:01:00 | 1                         |
| bill@test.com  | 3             | 83       | 2019-11-00 00:02:00 | 1                         |
| joe@test.com   | 4             | 84       | 2019-11-00 00:03:00 | 2                         |
| mike@test.com  | 5             | 85       | 2019-11-00 00:04:00 | 1                         |
| sue@test.com   | 6             | 86       | 2019-11-00 00:05:00 | 2                         |
| joe@test.com   | 7             | 87       | 2019-11-00 00:06:00 | 3                         |
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.6.41, I'll add that as a tag. Thank you for thinking of that. @Meckel'sDiverticulum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in earlier versions of MySQL:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@ce = customer_email, @rn + 1,
                  if(@ce := customer_email, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as occurrences
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by customer_email, created_at
     ) t cross join
     (select @ce := '', @rn := 0) params;
```

In MyQL 8+, I would recommend `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_email order by created_at) as occurrences
from t;
```

Comment: Took a while (which is fine for my situation), but it worked! Thanks for the help. Can you explain or provide a reference to this answer? I vaguely get what's going on with the if statement relating to the params table in the cross join. But it would be nice to have a more in-depth understanding.

Comment: If you want to ignore repeated values within the same partition then using `dense_rank()` in place of `row_number()` might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just do a window count:

```
select 
    t.*,
    count(*) over(partition by customer_email order by created_at) occurences 
from mytable t
```

You don't need an `order by` clause at the end of the query for this to work (but you need one if you want to order the results).

If you need to filter on the results of the window count, an additional level is needed, since window functions cannot be used in the `where` clause of a query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        count(*) over(partition by customer_email order by created_at) occurences 
    from mytable t
) t
where occurences < 2
```

Comment: Forgot to my mention my MySQL version (5.6). Thank you for the response, looks promising for newer versions.