# Select the occurrence order of the same record next to each record in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is what I'm trying to do (this is in SQL Server 2008).

I have this table:

```
Michael | 
Joe     | 
Peter   | 
Roger   | 
Peter   | 
Roger   | 
Joe     |  
Peter   |  
Roger   |
```

I need a column added to this table that would enumerate the occurrence number of each records, i.e.:

```
Michael |  1
Joe     |  1
Peter   |  1
Roger   |  1
Peter   |  2
Roger   |  2
Joe     |  2
Peter   |  3
Roger   |  3
```

Each new occurrence of the same entry would get an increment of 1.
`select count(*)` only gets the overall count of a particular item. `row_number()` does the count regardless of whether the item is unique or not. So I need a combination (sort of) of both. I believe `previous()` could be used but I'm on 2008, so no luck there.
Is there a way to accomplish this with one `select` query.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180954/how-to-increment-count-of-occurences-of-column-value-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment count of occurences of column value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180954/how-to-increment-count-of-occurences-of-column-value-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you purple and ggordon. The post refers to MySQL and the proposed solution doesn't actually fulfil the OP's requirements per what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd just need to alter the use of row number slightly with a partition clause as below

```
select 
    *
    ,row_number() over(partition by names order by names) as rn
from
    table
```

Comment: That is on-track. The correct SQL syntax is: SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by names ORDER BY names) AS Row_Number from names_table [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1). Pls edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, one question - why would we need the order by after partitioning? It's an optional clause AFAIK and isn't required in this particular case.

Comment: I tried running it on MS SQL 2008 and it didn't work without ORDER BY. Not sure if later versions handle it as optional. If you have a definitive answer, let me know.